# After sign up with Devise redirect paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So i'm using Devise gem for handle my Users in rails app,
i already found the Devise methods: **after_sign_in_path_for** and **after_sign_out_path_for** that you use in the **Application_controller** but i want to have a specific path for after a successful **sign_up** but Devise didn't have that method, what can i do?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Comment: thanks, but i already got a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this, the path depends of a boolean state

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if(current_user.firebase_form === false) 
    user_form_firebase_user_form_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end
```